# Creating fewer files when freezing a Python application

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm using cxFreeze to freeze my Python application. All seems to be working as expected but peering into the build directory got me thinking...

Is there a way I could have fewer files in the build directory?

Currently, there's a bunch of PYD files and the necessary DLL files lying around. Then I have some configuration files (custom) and the rest of the stuff is thrown into a library.zip file. Is there a way I could bundle pretty much everything into the library.zip file so I could have fewer files in there?

(This seems to be more a-nice-clean-directory fetish than a real "issue" but nonetheless, sometimes you've just got to fulfill the curiosity/fetish)

Thanks a ton guys (in advance).

Comment: I have only tried cx_Freeze once, but settled on using py2exe when necessary. A couple benefits of py2exe are that you can trim the unused/unneeded modules beyond what the compiler guesses are needed, and you can have all the libraries together in a zip-compressed file... which leaves a very clean install directory for the neatniks ;)

Comment: I choose to stick with cx_Freeze because it was cross platform but i don't get to be a neatnik. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is cross-platform too, and has more features than cx_Freeze, but doesn't support Python 3. See also [py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file).

Comment: Not supporting Python 3 is a showstopper these days. That was a reason for me to switch from PyInstaller to cx_Freeze.