# Change folder structure in Python cx_Freeze project

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I made a Python application, and I wanted to construct exe file to simplify sharing among Windows users. I used:

- Python 3.6.1
- cx_Freeze module 5.0.2

I got an exe file, but the final structure made me cry:

- executable file
- zip archive with Python 3.6
- 3 dlls (python, sqlite, vcruntime)
- 21 folders
- 10 pyd files

In my opinion, it is not convinient for users and I would like to move folders and pyd files into separate folder or archive (it would be better). Does anybody know to do it? Current `build.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = 'myapp',
    version = '0.1',
    executables = [Executable(
        script='__main__.py',
        targetName='myapp.exe',
        icon='myapp.ico'
    )]
)
```

What options should I add to my `setup` function? Is it possible to do in current versions of Python and cx_Freeze? Or should I patch cx_Freeze like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266589/5658348)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been almost solved in the version 5.1. There were only 5 items in the build directory:

- lib folder
- exe file
- 3 dlls (python36, sqlite, vcruntime)

It was ok for me, but exe file did not work. There was an error `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'codecs'`.

The answer has been found [here](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/325). There is an error in the current version (5.1 at the moment), but the patch has been already done. Unfortunately, new version (5.1.1) is not in the PyPI.

Nevertheless solution is pretty simple: to build `cx_Freeze` from the sources. It is mentioned [here](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/325#issuecomment-346438229). (Visual Studio is needed, I used 2013 one). Or you can just wait for a while, I hope new version will be in the PyPI soon.

Answer (score 0):

cx_Freeze 5.1.1 is in the PyPI in the meantime, see https://pypi.org/project/cx_Freeze/#history ; cx_Freeze 6.0b1 is there as well as pre-release.

To simplify sharing among Windows users, you can let cx_Freeze build a simple installer by running the setup script as:

```
python build.py bdist_msi
```

See http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils-setup-script

Alternatively, in order to make a more customizable installer, you can use script-based tools such as [NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) and run the installer-generating script after the cx_Freeze setup script.