# Help On Python program that can use to compile python coding into a standalone .exe file

Tags: python

I am currently working on a python program with the use of wxpython to make out a gui application. However, i wish to compile my application to be like a standalone application where people can just get the .exe file and run it without installing python and wxpython. I am not sure if it is possible, thus i hope that someone can give me some guidance on this. Also, if it is possible, please tell me what program should i use to accomplish that.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [py2exe - generate single executable file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Comment: a quick search of "python executable" will give a few more duplicate matches...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a frozen binary. You can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) for this purpose.

For what it's worth, if you ever need to make executables on a unix system, you can use [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze), a utility that comes with Python.

Answer (score 1):

For a nice cross-platform solution, I always recommend [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (actually, I find it better than py2exe even just for making a Windows-only executable -- it can do code signing, can seamlessly incorporate "big, hairy" libraries such as PyQt, etc;-).