# how to make installer or exe of python code

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Hi,
I have a python project and wanted to make a exe for windows.
In my project I am using pyqt,python and MiKTeX , xlrd.
How to bundle the project so that user in windows can run the exe and every package get install. 
I am not able to find any reading materials on this.
Any link will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), unless you want to hide your logic. I use it to deploy my programs inside the company I work at and it works perfectly well