# cx_Freeze and moving files around

Tags: python, cx-freeze

In cx_Freeze, is it possible to move all pyd files and the library.zip to some subdirectory?

I can live with two dlls along with the exe but I'd rather hide 15 other files from my users, even if only in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [appears](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=tZ42hjaRunvkObFq0bKxVdg&output=html) to be impossible. Use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), or [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) if possible. See also [py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file).

Comment: thanks, generating a single executable file should be a nice solution