# Make a py2exe exe run without a console?

Tags: python, py2exe

Does anyone know how to make an exe with py2exe run without the black console? and bundle up all the pyd files etc into just one exe file?

Answer (score 1):

For one exe file, use this setup (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113014/1713149)):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "single.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    windows = [{'script': "pytho.py"}],
)
```

edited for py2exe x64 support
64-bit does not have zipping

using: python 2.7 amd64