# Converting .pyw to .exe

Tags: python

If I use py2exe to convert a .pyw to a .exe, will it run with a console open? I have some Python files I want to run in the background that I'm going to need to have on computers that don't have Python installed.

Comment: It should run on computers without python

Answer (score 6):

Use the `windows` parameter (instead of `console`) in your py2exe configuration, and no terminal window will appear.

[Make a py2exe exe run without a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480595/make-a-py2exe-exe-run-without-a-console)