# Python .exe file opens commnad window

Tags: python, user-interface, exe, pyinstaller

I have compiled my python script in an .exe file via `PyInstaller`.

The problem is that, now when running the .exe application, two windows are opened, one is the GUI interface which is ok, but the other is kind of windows command window, which I would like not to open.

Would it be possible?

Comment: -1 Please don't make us guess how you made an exe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) try to use `-w` option when building your app.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked how I was using pyInstalled and no, I am not using -w option, I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: Or using `console=False` in spec

Answer (score 6):

If you are using py2exe,

```
setup(windows=['your_code.py'], ...)
```

instead of `console`

See [Make a py2exe exe run without a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480595/make-a-py2exe-exe-run-without-a-console)

*UPDATE*

[pyinstaller manual](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/develop/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw) says

```
 -w, --windowed, --noconsole
```

use a windowed subsystem executable, which on Windows does not open the console when the program is launched. This option is mandatory when creating .app bundle on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks mskimm, but no, I didn't used py2exe since I didn't know how to. I used PyInstaller instead