# I wrote a pygame program but when I try to use py2exe I don't get an exe in the dist

Tags: python, pygame, exe, py2exe

I wrote a program called Hello.py that looks like this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

# set up pygame
pygame.init()

# set up the window
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello world!')

# set up the colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# set up fonts
basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up the text
text = basicFont.render('Hello world!', True, WHITE, BLUE)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
textRect.centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery

# draw the white background onto the surface
windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

# draw a green polygon onto the surface
pygame.draw.polygon(windowSurface, GREEN, ((146, 0), (291, 106), (236, 277), (56, 277), (0, 106)))

# draw some blue lines onto the surface
pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4)
pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (120, 60), (60, 120))
pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (60, 120), (120, 120), 4)

# draw a blue circle onto the surface
pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, BLUE, (300, 50), 20, 0)

# draw a red ellipse onto the surface
pygame.draw.ellipse(windowSurface, RED, (300, 250, 40, 80), 1)

# draw the text's background rectangle onto the surface
pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, (textRect.left - 20, textRect.top - 20, textRect.width + 40, textRect.height + 40))

# get a pixel array of the surface
pixArray = pygame.PixelArray(windowSurface)
pixArray[480][380] = BLACK
del pixArray

# draw the text onto the surface
windowSurface.blit(text, textRect)

# draw the window onto the screen
pygame.display.update()

# run the game loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

And I have a program called setup.py that looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import pygame

setup(window=['Hello.py'])
```

when I run py2exe, it makes a dist folder but inside the folder there is no exe file, just the other files it creates. I hate to keep asking questions like this but I'm a little short for time and don't have time to play 20 error messages with my computer. I am currently running windows vista.

Comment: See this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Comment: Also the option in `setup` should be `windows` not `window`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pygame already has a default program for using pygame and py2exe, Pygame2exe.
Here is a [link](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe?parent=CookBook) to it.
Just fill in the arguments in BuildExe.**__*init*__** and run it. You don't even have to run it in console because it adds "py2exe" to the arguments.
Hope this answer helps!

Comment: Are there any modern alternatives to the deprecated and nearly removed distutils extension?