# How can i make a application with single .exe file using python?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

I made a application.exe from application.py using "pyinstaller".There are so many .dll file generated during this process. How can i make a application with single .exe file

Comment: This is not a duplicate, since it's asking about `pyinstaller`. The other question is asking about `py2exe`.

Comment: Actually the top answer there does answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/112713/4752883

Answer (score 64):

Have you tried the `--onefile` option to PyInstaller? See the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#what-to-generate) on the subject.

Comment: I thought I was going to need some other packer or something, what a simple solution to something I was already using. Thanks!