# Converting PyGTK to exe

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, py2exe, pyinstaller

I've been looking around for hours now. The only thing that makes sense to me is http://fnch.users.sourceforge.net/portablepygtkwindows.html But it takes up >40MB of space and it is too big for me.

Other tutorials are either too complicated for me to go through them or the results I obtained didn't work.

I've tried py2exe but the `import gtk` fails.

I've tried pyinstaller. The GTK files were included but not the glade file.

I would wish to have it all in a single standalone .exe. But now my priority is to have it properly working in windows without Python. Any effort to help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Some instructions on [py2exe and pygtk](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyGTK) are available. You should be able to have your whole program in a single exe file, but not the GTK library, which will need to be copied:

> Once that's done, you'll need to copy the etc, lib and share directories from your GTK+ install (not the pygtk install) to the dist dir py2exe created.

Looks you can also [ship data files with pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/develop/project/doc/Manual.html#accessing-data-files).

Comment: Seriously, thanks a bunch! I've managed to convert it into exe. I tried to compare with minty's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file and I added `{'bundle_files': 1}`. It does convert it into just 4 files (good enough). However my program won't run. Changing bundle_files to 2 also won't run. But when bundle_files is 3 (default), it works again. What am I missing?

Comment: From that answer, `bundle_files = 2` should not run, as python interpreter is missing, but `bundle_files = 1` should. I've never used these tools, only googled a bit, so I can't really give you an explanation here...