# how to use python to access library files in the MSYS2 environment

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pygtk, msys2

MSYS2 maintains pygtk. I want to use python to access pygtk in MSYS2 environment,Because when i use pyinstaller getting an executable file,it mention that pygtk should be install. Python is not in MSYS2 environment,but i want get the pygtk of MSYS2. Can it be achieved?
Thanks!

Comment: There are indeed Python packages for MSYS2 so maybe you should try just using the tools provided by MSYS2 instead of trying to integrate with third-party tools which might have been compiled with incompatible toolchains.

Comment: When freezing with pyinstaller you must copy manually (or by a hook, or rather added data in your spec file) the `etc`, `lib` and `share` folders from your gtk/gnome installation. This folders can be in different places depending on your installation. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799317/converting-pygtk-to-exe