# Creating single EXE using py2exe for a Tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe

I'm trying to use minty's solution provided on this link to generate a single exe file for my Tkinter based program:

[py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Here's what I wrote in the setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(windows=[{'script': 'filename.py'}], \
            options={"py2exe": {"includes": ["decimal", "Tkinter", \
            "tkFileDialog", "csv", "xml.dom.minidom", "os"], \
            'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': False}}, \
            zipfile = None)
```

It creates a 'tcl' folder for Tkinter stuff even though I have specified bundle_files = 1. Plus it also generates some other exe w9xpopen.exe. My actual exe, however, does not run, and it doesn't give any errors either. It doesn't even work if I remove all those includes.

Any thoughts on what I could be missing here? I'm working on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Does it work without `bundle_files`?

Comment: It does that way, but I intend to bundle everything into a single exe file. bundle_files = 3 works fine.

Comment: some posts indicate that bundle_files 1 & 2 don't work with 64bit system...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to [this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/bugs/108/), you have to edit `site-packages/py2exe/build_exe.py` and add `"tcl85.dll"` and `"tk85.dll"` to the `dlls_in_exedir` list. This will get it to run, although you'll still have the `tcl` folders, and those two dlls will be there along-side the exe. But it's way better than `bundle_files=3`.

```
        self.dlls_in_exedir = [python_dll,
                               "w9xpopen%s.exe" % (is_debug_build and "_d" or ""),
                               "msvcr71%s.dll" % (is_debug_build and "d" or ""),
                               "tcl85.dll",
                               "tk85.dll"]
```