# Create a single-file executable using py2exe

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe, distutils

I have written a python code which displays a window using Tkinter.
It also calls another python file present in the same folder.
I converted the .py files into a .exe file using py2exe. But i am facing the below issues:

1. The output (in dist folder) is a set of files and not a single executable file.

   - As per my understanding using the `'bundle_files':1,'compressed':True`, i should be getting a single file.
   - Now i have two .exe files and 1 folder: **w9xpopen.exe,myframe.py**(this is my file) and folder "**tcl**"
2. The icon is not changed.

   - I had mentioned `"icon_resources":[(0,"icon.ico")]` in the "windows" section

Below is the **setup.py** i used:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, glob,sys,os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(

  options={'py2exe':{'bundle_files':1,'compressed':True}},
  windows=[{"script":'hr_data_downloader.py',"icon_resources":   [(0,"icon.ico")]}],
 data_files = [],
 zipfile=None
)
```

I had issues running the executable at first but after going through the below posts, i corrected it by explicitly adding the two dlls.

[Creating single EXE using py2exe for a Tkinter program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975018/creating-single-exe-using-py2exe-for-a-tkinter-program)

[py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Please let me know if it is possible to create a single-file executable by modifying the setup files or any other py2exe files.
Also please tell me why the icon is not shown for the created .exe

I am open to try other distribution utilities like py2exe if it can help me create single-file executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using pyinistaller.
Although it makes the exe considerably large, i am happy that i have only single file.

Below is what i did:

1. Installed pyinstaller, pywin32
2. Open command prompt
3. go to my code folder
4. use command `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed myframe.py`

The manual for pyinstaller has detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

**Pyinstaller can be used to generate a single executable file from a python project.**
**STEP 1 :**
Install Pyinstaller
https://www.pyinstaller.org/downloads.html
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/zipball/develop

**STEP 2 :**
Extract the file in python installed directory (C:\Python27\)
Remane the extracted folder to : pyinstaller
**STEP 3 :**
Now open command prompt in Python directory and
`use command : cd pyinstaller`
(To create exe)
`use command : python pyinstaller.py your_python_file.py`
(To create single exe)
`use command : python pyinstaller.py --onefile --windowed your_python_file.py`
(your_python_file.py : it should be placed in C:\Python27\pyinstaller\)

Output Folde : C:\Python27\pyinstaller\main\dist