# run python program via clickable desktop icon

Tags: python, user-interface, interface, createfile

I've made a python program using Tkinter(GUI) and I would like to enter it by creating a dedicated icon on my desktop. (I want to send the file to my friend, without him having to install python or any interpreter)

the file is a some-what game that I want to share with friends and family, which are not familiar with coding.

Comment: create a bat file which runs the python script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975018/creating-single-exe-using-py2exe-for-a-tkinter-program

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [Pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) to create a standalone .exe.

Run this from the Windows cmd to create a standalone executable file: `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --noconsole --icon=your_image_here.ico app.py`

Answer (score 1):

you can install Pyinstaller by using pip

> pip install pyinstaller

go to the directory where your file is saved and type:

> pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed path/to/your/file.py

--onefile (compresses your files into one .exe file)
--windowed (removes the console when you run your file) 
path/to/your/file.py (or simply file.py when you want to convert the file in the same directory)

if you have any error using it, remove the --windowed flag and run file.exe on command line to see the error

Comment: Hey! when in the cmd of the directory, pyinstaller.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command. any idea?

Comment: please try instaling it on your system too. pip install pyinstaller in your cmd or in any other way

Comment: `python -m PyInstaller`, **case-sensitive**...