# How do I create an all in one exe file from cx_freeze (or installer) from python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, exe, cx-freeze

I have made a GUI python script that I would like to share with my coworkers to improve productivity. I need a way to include everything in one file/directory for them to use. I tried the standard

```
python setup.py build
```

But it does not contain everything (tested on their pc's and I just get a quick command prompt popup and then it closes.)

It works fine on my machine, but I have other things installed (like python for example)

My setup.py is as follows:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [
        Executable("Blah.py")
]

buildOptions = dict(
        compressed = True,
        includes = ["Blah"],
        path = sys.path + ["modules"])

setup(
        name = "Blah",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Blah",
        options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
        executables = executables)
```

I have spent hours searching already with no luck. I feel like there is a way to include all needed file, I am just not sure how. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Some libraries are just not working well with cx_freeze. Run it on their PCs from opened console to see what is the error.

Comment: If you use the `Win32GUI` base ([see the docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html)), the error message should be displayed in a way that you can see.

Comment: what system do your cooworkers use ? I use linux, and windows with same configuration for my application (python 3.x, pyqt4, cx-freeze) and everything works well. If thread is still alive I can post my cx_freeze file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think pyinstaller is your best bet.. They do happen to have a Python3 version:

[py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki

pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/python3.zip

Answer (score 0):

You could try pynsist. It is an easy way to bundle Python applications for Windows and it has examples for all kinds of GUI toolkits:

- http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html

It does not rely on setup.py but on a separate config file that grabs all the necessary dependencies.

Repository: https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist