# How to pack archive to executable .exe file?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, exe, py2exe

I wrote a program in Python with GUI based on Tkinter and convert them to standalone windows program using Py2Exe, and now i have a big folder with help files and one .exe file.

Do you know any method to pack it all to one .exe file? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup a build script with `zipfile = None` in the config:

```
import py2exe, sys
from distutils.core import setup

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {
        'py2exe': {
            'verbose': True,
            'bundle_files': 1,
            'compressed': True,
            'dll_excludes': ['MSVCP90.dll', 'HID.DLL', 'w9xpopen.exe']
        }
    },
    windows = [{'script': "main.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

This will create a single executable.