# Python to executable

Tags: python, exe

I have made a text based adventure for my friends and I am wondering, since they don't have python interpreters, how can I convert a .py file to a .exe executable file?

Comment: This should do the trick http://www.py2exe.org/ Also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If on Python 2, use [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/). This supports versions 2.3 through to 2.7.
- If on Python 3, use [`cx_Freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). This supports versions 2.7 through to 3.4.