# Cannot compile two .py files into stand alone executable using py2exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot compile two `.py` files into stand alone executable that does not need to be installed using py2exe . I followed the instructions on [this post post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file) and wrote my setup file as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys, os

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows=[{'script': "main.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
    )
```

My problem however, is that I have two `.py files`, my main file `main.py`, and my `background_image.py` file (which contains base 64 image strings). As a result, py2exe compiles these two file separately as you can see here in this image:

[image]

As a result, I receive the following error when I try to run the main compiled file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 'main.py", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: No Module named 'background_image'
```

This is a reduced version of my program from `main.py`; the program draws a canvas with a background.

```
import tkinter as tk     
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import background_images

#image variables
background = images.background_image
close_icon = images.close_icon

#root window creation
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry(600, 600)

#canvas widget
photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=background)
width, height = photo.width(), photo.height()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bd=-2)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

and here is shortened background_image from `background_images.py`

```
background_image = """
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA #... continues on
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the background image as a data file:

```
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows=[{'script': "main.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
    data_files= [ ("prog",["background_image.py"])]
    )
```

Comment: Why? The error says there is `no module named background_image`, and yet other modules are compiled fine. I imported `background_image.py` in `main.py` so shouldn't it just work? Anyways, I have not been able to make your solution work.

Comment: @the_prole I realized at least part of the problem with why you couldn't get it to work (fixed above). Also, you are not importing `background_image.py`, so you need to add it as a data file. You may need to take a look at documentation to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bundle_files = 1, it has too many problems.  Suggest to use bundle_files = 2 and then use e.g. InnoSetup to create a one file installer.  If that doesn't solve it please provide a small self contained sample of your main.py, plus bg_image.py plus setup.py.

Comment: The idea was that I wouldn't have to use an installer. It's why I didn't use Inno. I will take your other suggestions into consideration, thanks.