# Unable to prevent console window from appearing with py2exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I compiled a `.py` file into a python byte code single executable file using `py2exe` according to the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file). Accordingly, my setup file looks like so:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "single.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

But now I have the annoying console window, which was easily solved using one of these solutions.

- change `.py` extension to `.pyw`
- change console to window in set up e.g. `setup(windows=["main.py"])`

But now these solutions no longer work.

Comment: Stupid question: have you tried `.pyw` and using `console` at the same time? <--This is on the same lines of "Is it plugged in?"

Comment: @AHuman Yep, tried this one as well.

Comment: http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/09/12/running-a-python-script-on-windows-without-the-console/ <--Might help

Comment: @AHuman these solutions work, but only with a setup file that doesn't create a single executable. I change my questions to make that part clear.