# How to convert byte code single executable into stand alone binary exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have successfully followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file) and have created a single executable albeit in byte code e.g. a `.pyc` extension. The question now is how to convert it to a binary executable. I read [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-can-i-create-a-stand-alone-binary-from-a-python-script.htm) that I should convert the bytecode into C arrays and compile with a C compiler. Is this the reccomended way?

Comment: Both py2exe and PyInstaller create .exe files, not specifically .pyc files, and no additional steps should be required.

Comment: @martineau But I wanted a stand alone binary exe, not this "bundled" .pyc file described [here](http://www.py2exe.org/old/)

Comment: @martineau Even if this bundled version can work on other platforms, I still have the problem of the window console which keeps appearing.