# Fatal Python error when trying to run an executable Python script

Tags: python, python-3.4, cx-freeze

I have a Python script that I have turned into an executable using `cx-freeze-4.3.4.win32-py3.4`. I have `Python 3.4` installed on a `Windows 7 64-bit` machine.

Here is my simple setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup( name = "myfilename" , 
       version = "0.1" , 
       description = "This is my file" , 
       executables = [Executable("myfilename.py")] , )
```

I ran `python setup.py build` from command prompt in the `C:\Python34` folder with both the script I was trying to convert and the setup.py file.
This created another folder called `build` within was another folder called `exe.win32-3.4`. In that folder I found my executable file, a bunch of `.pyd` files, a single `.dll` file, and a zipped archive called `library` of a bunch of `.pyc` files.

If I run the executable from within the `exe.win32-3.4` with the library zip archive it executes fine. However, without the library archive of .pyc files (basically if I try just to run the .exe by itself, which is what I am supposed to be able to do) the executable throws out this error:

```
Fatal Python error: cannot get zipimpirter instance

Current thread 0x000001b48 (most recet call first):
```

I did some preliminary searching around the web for potential resolutions to the issue but could not find anything substantial.  If anyone knows how to troubleshoot this issue that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The exe needs those other files in your build folder. cx_Freeze does not support making a single file exe. If you need to do that, see [this FAQ entry](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that link was exactly what I was looking for!...Shame I started doing everything in python 3.4 since you cannot use py2exe with that version...N I know that I have run a single python executable that I am assuming was created using py2exe and not cx-freeze...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables):

> Single-file executables
>
> cx_Freeze does not support building a single file exe, where all of the libraries for your application are embedded in one executable file.

For a single-file solution using py2exe and others, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/112698/208880).

In 3.5 there is also the [new zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html#zipapp) module, although the basic functionality has been around for a while.