# Compile Python to a standalone exe?

Tags: python, compilation, exe, py2exe

I need to make a python script into a standalone .exe file. I have tried to use py2exe using this compile code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['script.py'])
```

But all it does is spit out a folder with the exe file, as well as a bunch of other stuff. Problem is, I *cannot* run the exe file without it being in the same exact folder as the other files.

Is there a way to make a standalone .exe file that does not require any other files to run?

Comment: have you looked at [this tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) ?

Comment: you can set `bundle_files=1` fore more details at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/SingleFileExecutable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [py2exe - generate single executable file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Answer (score 0):

Use pyinstaller instead.

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki

When you use it, make sure you use the --onefile option, this will pack all the libraries into a single .exe file. You may need to use one of the developing versions, as it is an old project.

-Robbie

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would suggest the following for you:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

__author__ = 'you'

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options={'py2exe': {
        'bundle_files': 1,
        'unbuffered': True,
        'compressed': True}},
    console=['script.py'],
    zipfile=None,
    )
```

This will create a single exe file, from the script that you can run from anywhere on your machine.