# How can I use setuptools to create an exe launcher

Tags: python, compilation, exe, setuptools

I can install a python script as an exe file into "scripts" folder on windows.

1. How can I just create an exe launcher for a script without installing it?
2. Using 64-bit python, can I create an exe that will work with 32-bit python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late, but since this is the first result on google, I'll add my findings.

What creates the scripts is in fact not `setuptools`, which only registers the config, but `pip` when it installs a package. And there again, it's `distlib` shipped inside pip. The little script.exe's can be found in your pip installation folder in

> `pip\_vendor\distlib`

For example, the `t64.exe` will be the terminal (no gui), 64 bit version.

Long story short, those exe headers can be concatenated with a shebang text file and a zip file into a new exe file, where the shebang file contains a commmand to call this exe file with. When called with python.exe, it will recognize the attached zip file and run the `__main__.py` inside that.

The good news is, you can use the API to do all this for you. Assuming you want to create an exe `myexe.exe` that runs `myfunc` out of a module `mypackage.mymodule` on the same `python.exe` you are currently using, then you can do this:

```py
import sys
from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker

sm = ScriptMaker(
    None,    # source_dir - not needed when using an entry spec
    target_dir = ".", # folder that your exe should end up inside
    add_launchers = True   # create exe launchers, not just python scripts
)
# set the python executable manually
sm.executable = sys.executable.replace("pythonw", "python")

# create only the main variant (not the one with X.Y suffix)
sm.variants = [""]   

# provide an entry specification string here, just like in pyproject.toml
sm.make("myexe = mypackage.mymodule:myfunc")
```

The exe should now be in the `target_dir` that you provided above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Some additions: `sm.executable` can also be a relative filename like "python\\python.exe" which makes things portable.

`sm.make` accepts a dictionary argument `options`.  `options = {'gui':True}` results in an exe file without console window (like pythonw.exe).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using setuptools, you can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org) to create your executable files.

Just read the [tutorial page](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) to understand how to create them.

1. Install it by typing in your terminal:

   ```
   pip install py2exe
   ```
2. Create your .exe script (hello.py)

   ```
   print "hello world!"
   ```
3. Create your setup config script (setup.py)

   ```
   from distutils.core import setup
   import py2exe

   setup(console=['hello.py'])
   ```
4. Run your setup script by typing in your terminal

   ```
   python setup.py py2exe
   ```

   After that, 2 folders will be created inside the scripts folder.

   They'll be called '**dist**' and '**build**' folder.

   Inside the 'dist' folder you'll find an executable of your script.

   In our example, we compiled the hello.py file, correct? So, inside the dist folder we should find a **hello.exe** file.

> Q: Also, using 64-bit python, can I create an exe that will work with
>   32-bit python?
>
> A: No! You'll have to install a 32-bit python and compile using the
>   32-bit version.

**Hint**: create a virtual machine to compile your 32-bit programs.

Also you can take a look at:

- [YT Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3VoLjGA6jI)
- [PythonCentral Tutorial](http://pythoncentral.io/py2exe-python-to-exe-introduction/)
- [PythonTips Tutorial](http://pythontips.com/2014/03/03/using-py2exe-the-right-way/)
- [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Comment: The question was how he can use setuptools todo that.