# How to run script over windows without any install

Tags: python, python-2.7

if i create python code with .py and i want my friends get the code and it will work on theme computer (open files and print them).

how can i do that without install.

i mean i dont wont them yto install python.

i can do it as .exe or something?

thanks!

my code is stupid but required here so -

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    # Open a file
    fo = open("foo.txt", "r+")
    str = fo.read(10);
    print "Read String is : ", str
    # Close opend file
    fo.close()
```

Comment: Take look at this link, this should work for you: http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: You've shadowed a built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Py2exe

but there are more solutions here are two links 
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)