# How to make an executable?

Tags: windows

I'm not entirely sure what I need so please bare with my description of what I have and what I would like to accomplish.
Oh my Desktop I have a folder, I shall call it "Program". Inside is as follows:

```
Program
    /data
        console.py
        verify.py
        manuel.html
        style.css
        script.js
        /saves
            Lela.save
        /images
            img_1.png
            img_2.png
            img_3.png
    launcher.bat
    icon.ico
```

Is there any way that I can pack this huge(er than this) mess into an executable or something and then when it is clicked it runs the launcher.bat? Or is this not possible for Windows. I know you can use autorun.ini on a flash drive but don't think that will be a very effective way of solving the issue.

Comment: You want [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file

Comment: Will it work on Python 3.5.2?

Comment: @LèlaNull - Don't know, but you could also try [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which claims support for Python 3.