# Getting file (exe) when converting a .py to exe

Tags: python, py2exe, cx-freeze

I have a python file that I want to convert to an exe. It has icons, Pictures and other files that it loads up. It also used Tkinter, PILLOW, webrowser, os,
sys, win32api, and platform. I want it to create ONE file that I can send to someone, without the hassle of having it buried in a ton of files. I also want to protect some of the applications that it calls upon and icons blah blah blah, I can't do that when their in a folder that anyone can access. These are contained in the "recources" folder. To clarify, I want my converted file to look like figure 1 and not like figure 2. Any ideas?

Figure 1: https://gyazo.com/e7c41fd20444d9a5b3cd938ea9bf3873

Figure 2: https://gyazo.com/69782b3e60b4d5f111baadea0d37ba8a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [py2exe - generate single executable file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pyinstaller](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Your mileage may vary on the size of the exe but I liked it for my dinky programs at work!

Comment: Oh and when using it you have to put a command line arguments to make it package your code into a single exe file. I'll let you find it because I don't remember it offhand :)

Comment: how would i include things like libraries or other things like icons? Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Usually it searches through your code and includes the modules it needs. I'm not sure if it grabs image/date files too. Also not sure about icons, it puts a nice little pyinstaller icon on it but I'm sure it's customizable. Sorry I don't know more, just started using it myself!