# Clicking an icon will run or install my python Tkinter desktop app which can also be usable to any PC

Tags: python, tkinter, installation, exe, deb

I'm expecting suggestion or sample example to make a python tkinter desktop application installable to any environment like as anyone can install it and use it to his/her PC without any difficulties. I googled and got some example but couldn't reach to my goal. Actually i don't know where to start, what do i need. Below the sample project and i want to make this installable. The example from you may be .exe, .deb or something like this.
Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
time1 = ''
clock = Label(root, font=('times', 20, 'bold'))
clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


def tick():
    global time1
    time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if time2 != time1:
        time1 = time2
        clock.config(text=time2)
    clock.after(200, tick)
tick()
root.mainloop(  )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [py2exe - generate single executable file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate.  Do not ask people to provide an executable binary.  Python code can be run on any system with Python, but any executable has to be system specific.  Bundling a program using tkinter is especially hard because that requires a bundled tcl/tk system in addition to core python and a subset of the stdlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very easy and so simple if you use **Pyinstaller** which workable for windows and linux both. I had also problem like you and got solution from here.
you should try this. very easy example i had ever seen.

[go here and discover solution](http://pythoncentral.io/pyinstaller-package-python-applications-windows-mac-linux/)

Comment: yes i deserve this. thank you very much. really it's so easy.

Comment: it's my pleasure.