# Calling numpy in an exe created from a python program

Tags: python, numpy, exe

I am having trouble running an .exe file that i've created from python which uses `numpy`. After running the .exe from the cmd a log file is created with the text: `ImportError: No module named numpy` (even if it is installed on the computer). 
I assume the solution is to import numpy to the setup file but don't know how and if additional files are need to be copied to the file directory. How can I run the exe in a computer without numpy?

I used py2exe and this setup file:

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe, sys, os

    sys.argv.append('py2exe')

    setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "solver.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
```

)
Thanks!

Comment: By the way how you converted python file to exe? Which module you used (py2exe / cxfreeze or something else). Please make the question more specific, if possible post the code too.

Comment: I would recommend using cx_freeze to package your file to an exe. you dont have to worry about dependencies when using cx_freeze as you can specify the same in you setup.py file.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced this issue with `py2exe` (Seems to be a known issue, check comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113014/5103802)) and since I couldn't make or find a way to workaround it I decided to use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead. After installing you'll just need to go to your program's directory and run

```
pyinstaller solver.py --onefile
```

to create a bundled executable with no dependencies in a subdirectory called `dist`. PyInstaller is compatible with Python 2.7 and 3.3-3.5.