# How to make .py to .exe independent?

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I have a .py file and want to converrt it to .exe, I have tried by using py2exe but it created dist folder, and if I move the exe file out of dist it is not working.
How can I have single working .exe file?

Comment: See also this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

There may be an option to embbed all dependencies from the folder into the exe. Then you will be able to move it. For pyinstaller, the option is `-F` or `--onefile`.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows users**

Go to the sourceforge site, where the cx_Freeze project is hosted. And download the file corresponding to your version of Python.

After downloading it, launch the executable and let yourself be guided. Nothing too technical so far!

I invite you to go to the command line (Start > Run... > cmd).

Go to the scripts subfolder of your Python installation (me, C: \python34\scripts).

On Windows or Linux, the script syntax is the same: `cxfreeze file.py`.