# Python virtualenv export to windows

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I would like you to suggest me some way how non-IT person would install program I created.
So basically I have virtualenv with python with libs. I am looking for some program that would create something (some exe or whatever necessary) that I would just put on usb, and when another human copied it on newly installed windows pc, it would just work. Its going to be PyQT application.

I would easily be able to setup everything, but it needs to be dumb-proof way. Just some 'exe-like' solution that would do everything itself.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. If you feel like this is duplicate, please point me into right direction...but all examples I found needed at least little bit of "IT mind".

Comment: See this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyinstaller package is the best one! see : http://www.pyinstaller.org/

**with pyinstaller you can convert your .py files to .exe**

you should install ( pywin32 pakcage too ), then you can try this ( run this on your commandline ):

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico your_app.py
```

you can find all its commands on : https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html, https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script/